# how to provide 'make directory as source root' from pyCharm to terminal

Tags: python, path, pycharm

I have some problems with migrating to production:

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/PEP$ python ./dev_scrapers/jordan.py                                                                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "./dev_scrapers/jordan.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                        
    from utils import create_entity, create_id, custom_opener                                                                                                                                                                                 
ImportError: No module named utils
```

i have used pyCharm with button  'make directory as source root' 
how to execute such command in terminal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add your source root directory to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/your/source/root"
```

Comment: is there a way to do this inside the script? I tried sys.path.append("my_script_dir) without success

Answer (score 2):

You can set the environment variable PYTHONPATH within the terminal as suggested by the accepted answer. This has to be done every time you start a terminal. In the case you use a virtual environment, you can place the variable assignment, like `export PYTHONPATH="/your/source/root"`, in the file `venv/bin/activate`. Where `venv` stands for the name of the virtual environment directory.

Comment: Is this Windows or Linux command? Does it override the existing value?

Comment: @variable Works on Linux and macOS. Can't tell about Windows. The example overwrites any existing value in `PYTHONPATH`. To append a value use `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/your/source/root"`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set directory as root (and fix the unresolved import issue) doing the following:

from `pycharm>Settings>Project>Project Structure` select your project and from the file tree, select your django project directory then click the blue folder `Source` button to define the directory as your source.